# Images wiped out by virtualssuser

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor

Bit of an unusual one. Came into work one morning to be told images are missing from multiple components within Sitecore.

Live appears to be unaffected. 
Carousels and other components with images within Sitecore are blank. The image item is still there, and the image is still in the media folder, but the image item is as though someone has pressed clear and then saved.
All affected items had last been edited within a couple of minutes and were done by the user **virtualuser**.

Some users have tried making changes to some of the components (changing text and such) and when publishing it's pushed the empty image over to pre-live.

Has anyone encountered anything like this before? What could have caused this? It's the first time I've seen this since taking over 2 years ago.

We're using Sitecore 8.0 (rev. 150121).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `virtualssuser` is the user that's used by the Content Testing feature to preemptively generate screenshots for content. I'm not sure why it'd be wiping out your valid content, but you could always disable it if you don't use that feature (it's disabled by default in 8.1u3+): https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecore_development_team/posts/screenshot-settings-for-content-testing

Comment: Yeah I've since disabled it as it's not something we do use. I've never heard of it actually editing files though and the only references I've seen on the internet are about people seeing it inside their active users list.

Comment: Yep, same for me. I've disabled it for performance reasons (and active users after a deployment), but your case is worrisome.

Comment: Do you use Sitecore PowerShell Extensions? Any possibility that someone ran a bad script that wiped out the content/media?

Comment: Sorry was off yesterday. I see 2 buttons for powershell console and powershell toolbox. console brings up a white box, toolbox doesn't do anything. I cant imagine anyone would be running scripts though. I'm the only developer using it. The client just use the basic cms features